# Storing and retrieving stats for entities in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm looking for a way to store and retrieve statistics about some of my Entities in GAE datastore.
Lets say i'm storing these Models:

```
NewsSource(db.Model)

Article(db.Model)
   NewsSource
   CommentCount
   VoteCount
```

So each Article has a NewsSource, votecount and comment count and a NewsSource has multiple Articles.
The Commentcount and votecount props could be updated frequently.

Now lets say i want to be able to retrieve stats about Newsources that tell me how many votes and/or comments the newssource has per week (or day or some other period) for the last x weeks (or other period).

I came up with this:

Have a cron job for each period that i want stats about. So one that runs every week and one that runs every day.
Then this cron job will loop over the Newssources and for each newssource, fetch all articles, process the data and store Stats in datastore as a separate Entity.

But there must be something better. Are there any existing patterns to handle these kinds of problems?

Thanks